# Eclipse reporting problem in my web.xml, but it is processed fine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm using Google App Engine with the Google plugin in Eclipse, here is the header of my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

Based on some of the GAE documentation, I added this:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However Eclipse reports an error at "url-pattern":

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'.
>   One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":web-resource-name}' is expected.

I can start the app and it seems to process the web.xml file just fine, but I don't like the fact that Eclipse is reporting an error.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well, the error seems pretty straightforward - a web-resource-name tag it expected before the url-pattern :)

cheers

Comment: Could you Please give a sample Code plz

Answer (score 9):

Just to add exact code

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>tasks</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/tasks/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @peshkira says, the problem is a missing  parameter.  But since the web.xml file is generated by Google tools, I thought there might be something wrong with the Google tools that were generating the files.

For my part, I was following https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/mapreduce_config#the_webxml_file to try out Google Modules (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) and the Web Tools Platform (WTP) (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform) for Eclipse.

So I filed a support ticket with Google Cloud Support and here is the answer they provided:

> After some research, this is due to the `<web-resource-name>` actually
>   missing. It's not absolutely needed within the code, but is
>   recommended as per our documentation[1].
>
> Here's an example of how to resolve it. I've also confirmed it fixes
>   the error on my end:

```
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </web-resource-collection>
</web-resource-collection>
```

> I'll also go ahead and make a recommendation to add this to our source
>   files, as they should technically be there.
>
> Thank you for reporting this.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Albert Cloud Platform Support
>
> [1] Security and Authentication:
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication