# AppEngine Security Constraint w/ Invalid Content was found starting with element url-pattern

Tags: google-app-engine

Im using Eclipse and AppEngine SDK 1.7.5.

I tried to validate war folder in my Google App Engine project. There is Invalid Content with my web.xml:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. 
One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":web-resource-name}' 
is expected.    web.xml /project/war/WEB-INF    line 121    XML Problem
```

This is the xml referred on the error:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 8):

It's a dup, see: [Eclipse reporting problem in my web.xml, but it is processed fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796692/eclipse-reporting-problem-in-my-web-xml-but-it-is-processed-fine)

Anyway, try adding a web-resource-name element as follows:

```
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
```

Comment: +1 for showing the solution instead of linking to documentation the asshats at Oracle took down.