# Web.xml issue cannot find declaration

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, xsd, web.xml

This is the start of my web.xml in which the errors occur

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee; http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Eclipse shows these 2 errors :

`Error 1 : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'. web.xml /"app.module"/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF   line 5  XML Problem`

`Error 2 : Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.jboss.tools.as.catalog_3.2.4.v20170308-1740.jar!/schema/xsd/jboss-ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd).`

Comment: Do have </web-app> after it?

Comment: yes it ends with `</web-app>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">
```

Comment: Now this issue is gone but another appeared i have this                 
        `<filter-mapping>
  <url-pattern>/proxyrest/*</url-pattern>
  <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
 </filter-mapping>`                                                                                                                                                                           
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":filter-name}' is expected.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796692/eclipse-reporting-problem-in-my-web-xml-but-it-is-processed-fine